# failed some test cases of a Ghost Leg code challenge

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this [Ghost Leg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Leg) Challenge

and the program should find the number of the vertical line number which leads to the most left side path(for example, in the picture below the program should return 3 as it can get to the most left line following the Ghost Leg Rule,where it should follow the horizontal line whenever it encounters one)

The parameter is passed like follows:

```
7 4 5  // lines[1] refers to length of each vertical line, the number of vertical lines,the number of horizontal lines
1 3 1  // from lines[2~L-1] each line refers to the a_i, b_i, c_i length of a horizontal line(pls check the picture) 
3 2 2
2 3 5
3 4 4
1 6 6
```

[image]

and below is my Solution:

```
let lines = [ '5 5 8',
  '3 3 4',
  '1 3 2',
  '4 2 2',
  '2 1 2',
  '2 4 4',
  '3 1 1',
  '1 4 3',
  '4 3 4' ];
// convert the stdin to an two Dimentional array 
let newLines = [];
let log = console.log.bind(console)
for(var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    let eachLine = []
    let eachEle = lines[i].split(' ')
    for(var j in eachEle) {
        eachLine.push(parseInt(eachEle[j]))
    }
    newLines.push(eachLine)
}

// my way try to do it is the opposite way, like start from the vertical Line 1, and move back to the top following the rule, and return the line number it reaches
let cur_index = 1
let last_c_i = 7
let nodefound = [1]
while(nodefound !== []) {
    const filteredarr = newLines.filter(
        function(each) { 
            return (each[0] === cur_index && each[1] < last_c_i) || (each[0] === cur_index - 1 && each[2] < last_c_i)})
    if (filteredarr.length !== 0) {
        nodefound = filteredarr.reduce(function (prev, current) {
            return (prev[1] > current[1]) ? prev : current
        })
        last_c_i = nodefound[2]
    } else {
        return console.log(cur_index);
    }
    log('nodefound', nodefound)
    if (nodefound[0] === cur_index.toString() || nodefound[0] === cur_index) {
        cur_index++
    } else {
        cur_index--
    }
}
```

The solution passed a few cases and failed some, I can't check all the test cases so can't figure out what's wrong with it.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which cases did it fail and where did it go wrong?

Comment: I don't know which case it fails cause it's a challenge on a coding practise website@JackBashford